# ansible output printing unwanted things. how to format and display only specific data's

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-template

I am using ansible 2.4 in centos, trying to run the below script in remote servers and getting the output. Here the problem is yum info output is showing with json format also. But i need to display only the output. How to remove the json format.

```
---

- hosts: GeneralServer

  tasks:
  - name: Checking the service status
    shell: systemctl status {{ item }}
    with_items:
        - httpd
        - crond
        - postfix
        - sshd
    register: service
  - debug: var=service
  - name: Checking the package info
    shell : yum info {{ item }}
    with_items:
        - httpd
        - postfix
    register: info
  - debug: var=info
  - name: Executing the mysql running scripts in mysql
    shell: mysql -u username --password mysql -Ns -e 'show databases;'
    register: databases
  - debug: var=databases
```

Also i am new in callback Module. Please help me to resolve this issue.

## Is it possibile to display only stdout_lines values only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to play with different callback plugins to alter your output, e.g.:

```
$ ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=oneline ansible-playbook myplaybook.yml
$ ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=minimal ansible-playbook myplaybook.yml
```

But generally you would not avoid JSON, as it's how Ansible interprets data.

To reduce amount of info, you can use different technics. For example [json_query](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) filter.

Something like this:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ info.results | json_query('[].stdout_lines[]') }}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The answer is showing the info results exactly what i need. But, The code is printing Json as well.

Comment: Please note my comment: _generally you would not avoid JSON, as it's how Ansible interprets data._ You can always write your own callback plugin that prints data in the way you like.

Comment: Is there any links available for callback plugins reference. I am new in callback plugins and python.thanks

Comment: You can take [this](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.4/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/oneline.py) as example